# convert JsonArray to multidimensional primitive array in android

Tags: android, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to load my Android App's Data, which is several (float[][][][]) arrays.
I have successfully saved the mentioned arrays in a Jsonarray[] and then into a Jsonobject and finally saved the Jsonobject in a file, and I can already see my Array data in the saved file.
The problem I am facing, is that I don't know how can I retrieve my arrays from Jsonarray[]. Can anyone help me figure it out?

Here is my code for saving and reloading data:

```js
float[][][][] array1,array2;


//save them with JsonArray
        try {
            JSONObject data_Json = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray[] data_Json_Array = new JSONArray[2];
            data_Json_Array[0] = new JSONArray(array1);
            data_Json_Array[1] = new JSONArray(array2);
            

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
                data_Json.put(String.valueOf(i) , data_Json_Array[i]);

            String data_string =  data_Json.toString();
            //card_object is the JSONObject that I want to store.

            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/DATA_Json/myJasonData.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.write(data_string);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Log.d("Json Message: " ,"Done writing SD 'myJasonData.txt'");

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Json Error: " , e.getMessage());
        }



//Reloading arrays from jsonarray
        try {
            JSONObject data_Json = new JSONObject("/sdcard/DATA_Json/myJasonData.txt");
            JSONArray[] data_Json_Array = new JSONArray[2];

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
                data_Json_Array[i] = (JSONArray) data_Json.get(String.valueOf(i));

            array1 = data_Json_Array[0].?;    //what should I do here?

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Json Error: " , e.getMessage());
        }
```

And here is a snip from the format of my saved file:

```js
{"0":[[[[-0.0028548788,-0.092874765,0.003136588,0.14189568,-0.021741211],
        [0.08174173,-0.010640814,-0.187461,-0.0060287244,0.11080382
        ],[0.031616475,0.1487913,-0.035319127,-0.15309978,0.026076572],
        [-0.06813478,0.06970301,0.1274362,-0.036483698,-0.07061834],
        [-0.021916576,-0.04674671,0.040819954,0.061903775,-0.0038302275]],
       [[-0.014075075,-0.08870728,-0.0061528883,0.12072352,-0.02060319, ... 
         ,-0.0075482884]]]],"1": [-0.01438952,-0.009805424,-0.014918945,-0.002214666,-0.0074256146,0.0030185885,-0.004984356
                                  
And so on...
```

Comment: From what I see, you keep on file the JSON as an object and not as a settlement, is it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand your question very well, I am newbie to use JSON.

Comment: Sorry, you are saving your file in a JSON object and not a ArrayJSON, you can display the format as it is stored in the file?

Comment: I have several JasonArray, which all of them are being saved in the same Jsonobject and into same file. I have updated my question with a snip of my saved file. Thanks.